# Is there a way to request another app to be opened side by side in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Say if I want to request a translator to be opened in the top window. An pass some string for it to translate.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Do you mean something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228340.aspx?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, that seemed to be it. Thank you very much! Post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [launch the default app for a given URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228340.aspx) simply with the `Launcher` class, for example:

```
// The URI to launch
var uri = new Uri(@"http://stackoverflow.com/q/34740877/50447");

// Launch the URI
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

if (success)
{
    // URI launched
}
else
{
    // URI launch failed
}
```

This also supports custom URI schemes, so you could use a URI like `ms-drive-to:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076` to launch the driving app, and get directions to drive to that point in New York.

Similarly, you [can register your own URI scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228339.aspx) so that you can be launched. So, if you can't find an app that handles translation via URI activation, you *could* write own that *could* take URIs of the form `translate:{string}&from=en&to=es` And then have that launchable from other apps

Answer (score 1):

I think this sample will be helpful for you.
Click here:[How to launch an UWP app from another app](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-launch-an-UWP-app-5abfa878)

Following code is the core:
In your launcher app.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("test-launchpage1://somepath"); 
//if you don't use this option, the system will show a confim box when you open new app
var promptOptions = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions(); 
promptOptions.TreatAsUntrusted = false; 

bool isSuccess = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, promptOptions);
```

In you launched app:
In the package.appxmainfest, you need config launch sechme, like this:

```
<Package> 
  <Applications> 
    <Application> 
      <Extensions> 
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol"> 
          <uap:Protocol Name="test-launchpage1"> 
            <uap:DisplayName>LaunchPage1</uap:DisplayName> 
          </uap:Protocol> 
        </uap:Extension> 
      </Extensions> 
    </Application> 
  </Applications> 
</Package>
```

And in your app.cs of launched app, you need override event handler `OnActivated`, like this:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args) 
{ 
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol) 
    { 
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame; 

        if (rootFrame == null) 
        { 
            rootFrame = new Frame(); 
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame; 
            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed; 
        } 

        var protocolEventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs; 
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), protocolEventArgs.Uri); 
        Window.Current.Activate(); 
    } 
}
```